# Executing Main Class through pom.xml

Tags: java, xml, maven, program-entry-point

Guys I know I am asking a very silly question, but I am very curious like why my test is not running.

I have created simple maven project(no junits, etc just a simple main class) with one only main class in a test folder and I am trying to execute the same through pom.xml.

I have gone through the existing question's over here but that didn't resolve it

When I try to execute it I got the following output.

```
Running samplemav.TestOne
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.015 sec
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>samplemav</groupId>
<artifactId>samplemav</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.20</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>samplemav.TestOne</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Java Class

```
 package samplemav;
 public class TestOne {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        System.out.println("test");
    }

}
```

Regards

Comment: That's not how unit tests work. Maven doesn't execute `main` when it runs unit tests.

Comment: so u mean to say we cannot execute the main calss directly

Comment: Yes, you need to create test methods with `@Test` annotation, and maven will run each of them. check link from @Firoj's answer.

Comment: ok I need not to define the main method  in the test folder only the test cases,is that right?

Comment: Yes, the main method is useless for tests it's not going to run. Also no need to configure the plugin like you did, just put them in the srs/test/java folder and maven will run them.

Comment: Thanks Oleg for the information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use Junit for unit testing.

```
package samplemav;
import org.junit.Test;
 public class TestOne {

    @Test
    public void test() {

        System.out.println("test");
    }

}
```

And add test dependency your `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.11</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the discussion on the question in the comments.
As per my understanding you can execute the main app just fine through the mvn command. Check the below link.

[Building and Running a Java SE Application by Using Maven](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/Maven_SE/Maven.html)

follow the instructions as mentioned in the documentation.

In your case the command to execute will be

mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="samplemav.TestOne"

I am assuming you may not have to provide settings.xml path

You are using maven-surefire-plugin to build you app so obviously it will try to execute test project. Now because there is no classes in there it will obviously give you the output you received.

Comment: Don't know why you posted this, though there is a very small chance that OP is completely confused and was just trying to execute his application, this line "why my test is not running", his comments and him accepting an answer about how to run unit tests all indicate very strongly that this question is about how to run tests.

Comment: Its according to the question which says "Executing Main Class through pom.xml" and thats what he mentioned is trying to do. At least he would know and understand what he is assuming or trying to achieve is wrong and he has framed his question wrong.

Comment: to be precise the comment says "so u mean to say we cannot execute the main calss directly" and you are affirming to the wrong notion.

Comment: Hmm..., after rereading and rethinking you might be right or at least there is a reasonable chance that you are right, you earned yourself an upvote.